# How can I solve errors in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript. Below is my code with errors mentioned in comments. What is going wrong?

```
type BooleanAttributeName = string;
type PairedAttribute = {
    [_: string]: string | number;
};
type CompositeAttribute = [
    PairedAttribute,
    BooleanAttributeName | BooleanAttributeName[]
];
type Attributes = CompositeAttribute | PairedAttribute;

function SetAttributes(attributes: Attributes) {
    if (attributes.length === undefined) {
        for (const key in attributes) {
            console.log(key, attributes[key]); /*Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Attributes'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Attributes'.*/
        }
    }
    attributes.map((item) => { /*This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'string | number | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string | PairedAttribute | string[], index: number, array: (string | PairedAttribute | string[])[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' are callable. Type 'string' has no call signatures.*/ /*Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.*/
        if (item.length === undefined) {
            for (const key in item) {
                console.log(key, item[key]);
            }
        } else if (typeof item === "object") {
            item.map((BooleanAttributeName) => { /*Parameter 'BooleanAttributeName' implicitly has an 'any' type.*/
                console.log(BooleanAttributeName);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(item);
        }
    });
}

let sample: Attributes = [
    {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
    },
    ["BooleanAttribute1", "BooleanAttribute2"],
];

SetAttributes(sample);
```

I tried to use some concepts of narrowing from the [official TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) but still I am facing these problems.

I want to know what can be solution for the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some type casting and checking:

```
type BooleanAttributeName = string;
type PairedAttribute = {
  [_: string]: string | number;
};
type CompositeAttribute = [
  PairedAttribute,
  BooleanAttributeName | BooleanAttributeName[]
];
type Attributes = CompositeAttribute | PairedAttribute;

function SetAttributes(attributes: Attributes) {
  if (typeof attributes === 'object') {
    const attr = attributes as PairedAttribute;
    for (const key in attr) {
      console.log(key, attr[key]); 
    }
  }
  if (attributes instanceof Array) {
    const attr = attributes as CompositeAttribute;
    attr.map((item) => {
      if (typeof item === "object") {
        const it = item as PairedAttribute;
        for (const key in it) {
          console.log(key, it[key]);
        }
      } else {
        console.log(item);
      }
    });
  }
}

let sample: Attributes = [
  {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
  },
  ["BooleanAttribute1", "BooleanAttribute2"],
];

SetAttributes(sample);
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nANhAhgOwILGAJwJYBGArsBAHIoC20AvFAM655oDmA3AFCiRQAKKeHBAAmWJsVJQ6Abw5QoAbQD6ALgZNWAXTWN8rKAB8oaIpQIQcnAL6du0AMJxKYOPTykx%20CbUVy%20AoVFsLxIIABo-eCRUTGDCUIpqQ1gEZHRPeNJEiAVNDk1bcGgM73opKEdnV3cIEtDk-kEROtJODgAzIjQAY2A8ODQoAGUIYBaIegAKFDjStXH6AEooWXk8dqhJuzgNmfFQspojqAByOAIAKwhek%20XV%20ShugcYoPZxyt8yJ17LGwPHOA8oO04O9Jk80C8ANYQEBQZivYJ3PxAiH0aIAOkQcBYkxhIDCiNwCnxmkWbCgKKgVj8NLWG2mswO8MhwHQ3QgOygGBwOBQIGRqOewCJ7zon1KPwqThcbg8TNaVLeGMoKDAk0mNUoyxoAD4VlT6ZtthstVJjgAic5XXoWwVAh5okXucpmlC-ALNBUQQEO%20QgsFOqD4lnw4D2v3yNGY7G4-GE9wk2Fk31%20ukOqxQCCIejQe5%206PILE4zWkbWph7p%20RWcm0jg0jjIEX0KhgZDzb2HXzyfPB2EARjUFoAbihEEQIP2LREgfiAExD0fjiBz6e0meKC1RNKxfakKeErepGLjVeaCIFDgcEZjTuTFvOZDkoA) to playground